# Sqlalchemy Mixin class example and warning

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, warnings, mixins

when I tried the following example:
http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/declarative/mixins.html#mixing-in-association-proxy-and-other-attributes

i encountered the following warning:

SAWarning: This declarative base already contains a class with the same class name and module name as data.test.StringAttribute, and will be replaced in the string-lookup table.item.**name**

Should I be concerned about this usage?

Comment: It seems like your Mixin may be conflicting with code. Can you post what you have that's generating the error?

Comment: the code i used is the example from the link i posted. No other changes.